# How to set date in simple format "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Tags: java

I'm new to android. I'm developing an app in which a user will get the return date of his/her books.

I can successfully retrieve the date from an external server. The problem is I am putting the date as a text view and I am getting it in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`. But I would like the date in Simple Format `dd/mm/yyyy`. How can I do that? 
this i have done so far.

```
    String returndate = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DATE_TO);
    TextView lblreturndate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.returndate_label);
```

in lblreturndate i want format to be like "dd/mm/yyyy".

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have a look at SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String d = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct a SimpleDateFormat with this pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") ;
df.format(date);
```

For more information see `SimpleDateFormat` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)